# Spring @ResponseStatus returns empty response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, httpresponse

In my Spring API I wanted to handle responses from operations like create, put and delete with Spring's annotation  **@ResponseStatus**. Every endpoint works correctly but they always return empty response.

Why response from annotated endpoints is empty?

**Controller:**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/portfolios")
public class PortfolioController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@RequestBody Portfolio resource) {
        repo.save(resource);
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        repo.removeById(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: the response is empty as you are not returning anything from your void methods. But the empty responses should be delivered with the corresponding http status code. Did you check that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why response from annotated endpoints is empty?

Because your methods return `void` (means without body). Status code - it's not a body.

You can try this to return response with message explicity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<String> delete(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
   repo.removeById(id);
return new ResponseEntity<>("Your message here", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Instead of `ResponseEntity<String>` you can put `ResponseEntity<YourCustomObject>`and then return `new ResponseEntity<>(yourCustomObject instance, HttpStatus.OK);` It will be conver into JSON during response.

You also can make this:

`@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK, reason = "Some reason")`

and in this case you will return something like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1504007793776,
    "status": 200,
    "error": "OK",
    "message": "Some reason",
    "path": "/yourPath"
}
```